# Clickable areas of image (Mouseover event)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop, compose-multiplatform

Any idea of how to approach clickable areas on images? It would be great if in desktop mode (yeah the desktop mode is available now; see https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose) there was something like `onMouseover` so the view was highlighted when the mouse is hovering over it.

Answer (score 5):

In the Desktop Compose, you can achieve the mouse over actions using the input pointer.

Example:

```kotlin
Image(imageResource("circus.jpg"), Modifier.size(200.dp)
  .pointerMoveFilter(
    onEnter = {
      println("On Mouse(pointer) Enter")
      false
    },
    onExit = {
      println("on Mouse(pointer) Exit")
      false
    }))
```

Note: `pointerMoveFilter` is an extension function for `Modifier` so it's not only for images, we can use it for all components in Desktop Compose.

Ref: [Getting Started with Compose for Desktop - Mouse event listeners](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Mouse_Events#mouse-event-listeners)

Answer (score 2):

***Sep 2023***
Since `pointerMoveFilter` is deprecated, Try to use the [**hoverable**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).hoverable(androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,kotlin.Boolean)) modifier, like this :

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
val isHovered by interactionSource.collectIsHoveredAsState()
Text( // in your case Image
      modifier=Modifier.hoverable(interactionSource),
      text = "hover = ${isHovered}"
     )
```